# jmeter.bat wont execute properly, results in errorlevel=1

Tags: jmeter

I have a problem with initializing jmeter.bat. For some reason I get this mistake when I try to execute it. Jmeter.jar works properly. I tried to install java 8, jdk17, bellsoft-jdk11 (separately). I always get this mistake.

What would you suggest?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzlGb.png
Last line translation: press any key.

Comment: Can you share the command you are trying to run?

Answer (score 2):

I actually found what was wrong in my case. Proxies are blocked in my office due security reasons, so I used environment variable to pass through this. For environment variable was used my login and password, and my old password contained a quotation mark. When I changed password and reconfigured the environment variable, all became okay.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `java.exe` file of the JDK you want to use is in your operating system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) and it's first there (before any other Java software which may be installed already) and you're using original unchanged jmeter.bat file

1. Install Java SDK to some folder like `c:\java`
2. Add "bin" folder JDK to your operating system PATH like:

   ```
   set PATH=c:\java\bin;%PATH%
   ```
3. Verify that correct Java is being used by invoking `java -version` command
4. Install the latest stable JMeter (or at least cross-check your jmeter.bat with the one from [JMeter GitHub repo](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/bin/jmeter.bat)
5. Open it's "bin" folder in the same terminal Window
6. Run `jmeter.bat` in this terminal
7. It should open without any issues

If you want to make the change to PATH environment variable permanent use [setx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx) command like:

```
setx /M PATH "c:\apps\java\bin;%PATH%"
```

this way you won't need to repeat step 2 each time you want to run JMeter

More information: [Get Started With JMeter: Installation & Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans)